# How to get sub-categories of two parent category

Tags: magento

I had a main category (parent category) whose id = 5 & 37. I want to collection of its sub-categories. How can I do that?

```
$catid = array(5,37);


$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5);
$_subcategories1 = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(37);
$_subcategories2 = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
```

i want the collection which have children categories from both category id(5,37)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that from one select:

```
$subcategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array(5, 37))
    ->setOrder('parent_id', 'ASC');//if you want them somehow grouped by parent_id
foreach ($subcategories as $category){
    //do something with $category
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here i am giving you one example to merge two collection of category in to one collection

```
  $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $categoryOneId = 5;
    $categoryTwoId = 37;

    $categoryOne = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryOneId);
    $categoryTwo = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryTwoId);

    $collectionOne = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addCategoryFilter($categoryOne);

    $collectionTwo = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addCategoryFilter($categoryTwo);

    $merged_ids = array_merge($collectionOne->getAllIds(), $collectionTwo->getAllIds());

    $mergedCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $merged_ids);
```

hope this will sure help you.